How to Start an Azure Durable Functions Orchestration Directly from a Service Bus Message Without an Intermediate Function?
I'm working with Azure Durable Functions and currently have a setup where a Service Bus message triggers a function (process_service_bus_message) that then starts an orchestration function (process_workflow). My goal is to streamline this process so that the orchestration function is started directly from the Service Bus message, without needing the intermediate function.
Current Setup:

Service Bus Trigger Function (process_service_bus_message): Receives the message and starts the orchestration function.
Orchestration Function (process_workflow): Processes the data from the Service Bus message
Desired Setup:

I want to trigger the process_workflow orchestration function directly from the Service Bus message, bypassing the need for the process_service_bus_message function.
Questions:
Is it possible to directly start an Azure Durable Functions orchestration from a Service Bus message? If so, how can I set this up? Are there specific patterns or configurations required to achieve this? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!
This is the main function_app.py looks like:
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df
import logging
import json
from item_processor import handle_item
from summary_builder import build_summary

# Set up the Azure Durable Functions app with no authentication for HTTP triggers
app_instance = df.DurableApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app_instance.service_bus_topic_trigger(
    arg_name="incoming_data",
    topic_name="item-topic",
    subscription_name="main-subscription",
    connection="ServiceBusConnectionString"
)
@app_instance.durable_client_input(client_name="client_instance")
async def process_service_bus_message(incoming_data: func.ServiceBusMessage, client_instance: df.DurableOrchestrationClient):
    # Decode and log the message received from Service Bus
    data_payload = incoming_data.get_body().decode('utf-8')
    logging.info(f"Message received: {data_payload}")
    
    # Convert the message payload into a dictionary
    data_dict = json.loads(data_payload)
    
    # Initiate a new orchestration with the provided payload
    workflow_id = await client_instance.start_new("process_workflow", None, data_dict)
    logging.info(f"New orchestration started with ID: {workflow_id}")

@app_instance.orchestration_trigger(context_name="workflow_context")
def process_workflow(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    # Retrieve the input data for the orchestration
    input_content = context.get_input()
    
    # Parallelize the processing of each item
    task_list = [context.call_activity("handle_item", item) for item in input_content['elements']]
    processed_results = yield context.task_all(task_list)

    # Aggregate the processed results
    results_aggregation = {
        "process_id": input_content['processId'],
        "results": processed_results
    }

    # Build a summary report from the aggregated results
    final_summary = yield context.call_activity("build_summary", results_aggregation)
    logging.info(f"Orchestration finished. Summary report: {final_summary}")

    return final_summary

# Apply decorators to the activity functions with new names
handle_item = app_instance.activity_trigger(input_name="item")(handle_item)
build_summary = app_instance.activity_trigger(input_name="summary")(build_summary)


Short answer
No, you can't bind a Service Bus message directly to an Orchestration. You'll need to keep the trigger function that you already have.
How to think about it
The way I'd rationalise it (if it helps) is to think about what the Orchestration infrastructure is doing.
It stores a set of input parameters and also the replay state in-between executing its activities (see ^1), with that state being serialised as JSON (see ^2)
Now consider an HTTP Trigger, instead of Service Bus. You probably wouldn't want to send the entire HttpRequest object to the Orchestration because:

Performance. Repeatedly serialising and deserialising the entire HttpRequest between each activity call would be a lot of overhead. What if the body content was a large binary data stream?

Use-case. To avoid the above overhead, you'd want to control exactly which parts of HttpRequest get serialised for your particular use-case. Perhaps you'd know that your HTTP trigger is just some JSON, and parse that from the HttpRequest body - sidestepping the worries of handling a large binary stream through an Orchestration.


Summary
So, it makes sense that you define a Trigger Function. This lets you handle the various types of input binding in a way appropriate to the use-case, and then pass a simple input to the Orchestration which internally uses JSON serialisation for it. You can then treat them as separate concerns.
Hope that helps!
